# Count occurrences per data.table row

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table too large to melt/cast in RAM (millions of rows).

From that I need to extract the rows that do not have duplicate values per row. Duplicate zeros and NA are ok to keep.

In this MWE, the "Duplicates"-column is what I want to calculate.

```
DT <- data.table(C1=c(0L, 7L, 0L, 0L),
                 C2=c(0L, 0L, 0L, 4L),
                 C3=c(2L, 0L, 2L, 3L),
                 C4=c(0L, NA_integer_, 2L, 6L),
                 C5=c(1L, 3L, 1L, 1L),
                 c6=c(0L, 4L, 2L, 4L),
                 Duplicates=c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE))

DT.wanted <- DT[Duplicates==FALSE, ]
```

Number of columns vary.

Edit: Here is a for-loop example. Is way too slow.

```
DT <- data.table(C1=c(0L, 7L, 0L, 0L),
                 C2=c(0L, 0L, 0L, 4L),
                 C3=c(2L, 0L, 2L, 3L),
                 C4=c(0L, NA_integer_, 2L, 6L),
                 C5=c(1L, 3L, 1L, 1L),
                 c6=c(0L, 4L, 2L, 4L))
DT[, Duplicates:=FALSE]
for (i in 1L:nrow(DT)){
  dt.i <- data.table(table(as.integer(DT[i, ])))
  if (max(dt.i[V1>0, N])>1) DT[i, Duplicates:=TRUE]
}
```

Comment: I must use `data.table` or can I use other pkgs/base R?

Comment: As far as I know, only data.table can do this without rewriting the table. Not enough RAM for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is another data.table go at things...

```
DT[ lapply( data.table::transpose( DT ), 
            function(x) anyDuplicated( x[!is.na(x) & !x == 0] ) ) == 0, ]
```

Not sure how it holds up memory-wise.. but is is waaaaay faster than for-looping..

**benchmark**

```
# Unit: microseconds
#      expr     min         lq      mean    median         uq       max neval
#      loop 11764.5 12164.2010 13987.589 12725.601 13775.0010 25885.601   100
# transpose   524.5   550.3515   592.633   566.601   597.4515  1116.201   100
```

benchmark-code

```
mydata <- data.table(C1=c(0L, 7L, 0L, 0L),
                 C2=c(0L, 0L, 0L, 4L),
                 C3=c(2L, 0L, 2L, 3L),
                 C4=c(0L, NA_integer_, 2L, 6L),
                 C5=c(1L, 3L, 1L, 1L),
                 C6=c(0L, 4L, 2L, 4L))

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
 loop = {
   DT <- copy(mydata)   
   DT[, Duplicates:=FALSE]
   for (i in 1L:nrow(DT)){
     dt.i <- data.table(table(as.integer(DT[i, ])))
     if (max(dt.i[V1>0, N])>1) DT[i, Duplicates:=TRUE]
   }
 },
 transpose = {
   DT <- copy(mydata)
   DT[ lapply( transpose(DT), function(x) anyDuplicated( x[!is.na(x) & ! x == 0] ) ) == 0, ]
 },times = 100L )
```

Comment: This most definitely will also result in RAM issues, but you could combine this soltuon and my loop. Maybe split the data.table in 10 parts and apply this solution step-wise.

Comment: Yes, still RAM-intensive. Thanks for tip to split data.table

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution, that should still be slightly faster (~*3x*).

```
foo_dup <- function(x) {
  anyDuplicated(x[!is.na(x) & x != 0L]) != 0L
}

cols <- paste0("C", 1:6)
for (i in 1L:nrow(DT)) {
  set(DT, i, "Duplicates", foo_dup(unlist(DT[i, cols])) )
}

DT
   C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 Duplicates
1:  0  0  2  0  1  0      FALSE
2:  7  0  0 NA  3  4      FALSE
3:  0  0  2  2  1  2       TRUE
4:  0  4  3  6  1  4       TRUE
```

PS. I changed the example data names, `c6` to `C6`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method using base R + `data.table::rowidv` (about 8 times faster than chosen solution for 1mio rows of data):

```
mSD <- as.matrix(DT)
mSD[mSD==0L] <- NA_integer_
m <- cbind.data.frame(ROW=rep(1L:nrow(mSD), ncol(mSD)), COL=as.vector(mSD))
mcc <- m[complete.cases(m),]
dup <- unique(mcc$ROW[rowidv(mcc) > 1L])
DT[-dup]
```

timing code:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(0L)
nr <- 1e5L
nc <- 6L
dat <- as.data.table(matrix(sample(c(0L:7L, NA_integer_), nr*nc, TRUE), nrow=nr))
DT0 <- copy(dat)
DT1 <- copy(dat)
DT2 <- copy(dat)

mtd0 <- function(DT) {
    DT[ lapply(transpose(DT),
        function(x) anyDuplicated( x[!is.na(x) & !x == 0] ) ) == 0, ]
}

mtd1 <- function(DT) {
    foo_dup <- function(x) {
        anyDuplicated(x[!is.na(x) & x != 0L]) != 0L
    }

    cols <- copy(names(DT))
    for (i in 1L:nrow(DT)) {
        set(DT, i, "Duplicates", foo_dup(unlist(DT[i, ..cols])) )
    }
}

mtd2 <- function(DT) {

    mSD <- as.matrix(DT)
    mSD[mSD==0L] <- NA_integer_
    m <- cbind.data.frame(ROW=rep(1L:nrow(mSD), ncol(mSD)), COL=as.vector(mSD))
    mcc <- m[complete.cases(m),]
    dup <- unique(mcc$ROW[rowidv(mcc) > 1L])

    DT[-dup]
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(times=1L, mtd0(DT0), mtd1(DT1), mtd2(DT2))
```

timings:

```
Unit: milliseconds
      expr          min           lq         mean       median           uq          max neval
 mtd0(DT0)    999.47159    999.47159    999.47159    999.47159    999.47159    999.47159     1
 mtd1(DT1) 110725.50423 110725.50423 110725.50423 110725.50423 110725.50423 110725.50423     1
 mtd2(DT2)     64.79497     64.79497     64.79497     64.79497     64.79497     64.79497     1
```

Timings with 1e6 rows of data:

```
Unit: seconds
      expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 mtd0(DT0) 9.902526 9.902526 9.902526 9.902526 9.902526 9.902526     1
 mtd2(DT2) 1.234894 1.234894 1.234894 1.234894 1.234894 1.234894     1
```